# Get SHA256 file hash value without a filename from "shasum" in macOS

Tags: bash, macos, hash, sha256

On macOS (Mojave), doesn't the "shasum" command has an option, which returns only the hash value without the filename?

```sh
$ shasum -a 256 archive.tar.gz
35fe34e225a06d......00e72ee61a437b7226f9f   archive.tar.gz
```

My current workaround which works in macOS' default state (w/no additional install):

```sh
$ shasum -a 256 archive.tar.gz | awk '{ print $1 }'
35fe34e225a06d......00e72ee61a437b7226f9f
```

```sh
$ php -r "echo hash_file('sha256', 'archive.tar.gz'), PHP_EOL;"
35fe34e225a06d......00e72ee61a437b7226f9f
```

But, I want to make it simpler if there's a command option for it.

Is there any command options or do I have to make an alias of the workarounds?

Answer (score 5):

An array assignment works:

```
sha=($(shasum -a 256 archive.tar.gz))
echo $sha
35fe34e225a06d......00e72ee61a437b7226f9f
```

Or you can use cut:

```
shasum -a 256 archive.tar.gz | cut -f1 -d' '
35fe34e225a06d......00e72ee61a437b7226f9f
```

Comment: Or `sed 's/[[:space:]].*$//' < <(shasum -a 256 filename)` or `awk '{print $1}' < <(shasum -a 256 filename)` or parameter expansion `v=$(shasum -a 256 filename); echo ${v/[[:space:]]*/}`

Answer (score 0):

## Linux Command (sha256sums)

If you're looking for an alternative to this

```
sha256sum --check SHA256SUMS
```

## MacOS Command (shasum)

Then use this instead on MacOS

```
shasum --algorithm --check SHA256SUMS
```